# how can I create Navigation Bar Background to see UIImage background in UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview

I want to show you the results of the screenshot that I have face issues with it.

[image]

but I can see the setting has like that.

[image]

I have tried this code to make the background clear for iOS 13 and above.

```
    let app = UINavigationBarAppearance()
          
    let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
           
    app.backgroundColor = .clear
    app.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
         
    app.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    app.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    app.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    app.backgroundColor = .clear
   
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = app
               
             
    navigationBar!.standardAppearance = app
    navigationBar!.scrollEdgeAppearance = app
```

so it does not work as well. How can I make the Navigation bar visible the UIImage that built-in UITableView?

What about add blur background in iOS 14? I can't find it.

Let me know thanks!